# Why not make synthetic beings?

Tags: magic, robots

In my story, an organization of mages has super-stringent entry requirements.  They have to be as dead sure you'll never abuse magic as it's possible to be before they let you in.  However, they're embroiled in a war and it is extremely rare for them to find someone they trust.  I want to keep the numbers of this order very low, so:

Why don't they just make synthetic soldiers?  Why not just *make* minds they know they can trust, then give those minds bodies?

Comment: As in synthetic soldiers at the golem level or full on synthetic human level?

Comment: I'm holding off voting to close until I see if people can make some good answers, but I fear this topic is broad.  There's *so* many variants of synthetic soliders in the worlds of fiction, each of which has its own particular nuances.   I would, however, ask two pairs of questions which I think may get the ball rolling:  1) What's different about synthetic soldiers from non-synthetic ones?  Could you get away with just having a bunch of babies and indoctrinating them instead?  2) Why don't we use synthetic soldiers today... or do we?  Is a modern Predator drone a synthetic soldier?

Comment: Ethical reason: growing humans face the same issue as cloning, why should we denied their rights since we accepted their existence? An autonomous car tried to avoid incoming collision from the front must choose to veer to the sides to save the driver, at that moment it's sensor picked up a truck to the left and a cyclist on the right... think about the aftermath and how is a synthetic human any different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ever met a parent whose child grew up exactly the way the parent wanted? I haven't. Even the ones that came close, the parents weren't confident of that result when they started the process. The problem with sentience is that it comes with free will. Every action you take to shape that will goes into the feedback loop. Maybe they take your orders well. Maybe they resent you. Maybe they pretend to love you until your defenses are low.

Creating a synthetic intelligence gives you better trust than meeting strangers -- family bonds do mean something even in the most dysfunctional family. But I'm guessing it isn't much better than meeting strangers and trying to form that trust.

Answer (score 3):

Sentient intelligence is a complex thing to create. I imagine it's something that would take quite some time and energy to create. So, there is the time/resource commitment that would at least limit the number they can create if not their willingness to commit to making them entirely.

Then you have to factor in the upkeep on whatever bodies you create for them. Stone golems won't have as much upkeep as an artificial organic lifeform. Maybe they are a construct that needs to be fed magical energies so they can continue to move their bodies.

Or, perhaps they tried before and it backfired on them. Maybe these artificial creatures were easy to manipulate by a member who went rogue and turned them on their creators.

Comment: Dune used the approach in your third paragraph.  "Thou shalt not make a machine in the likeness of a human mind."  Also interestingly, Dune had a related weakness for those machines: "The weakness of thinking machines is that they actually believe all the information they receive, and react accordingly."